# Get n number of points from angle 0 to 2π using an array operator like map or reduce?

Tags: javascript, pi

Imagine needing the points to draw a sine wave:

```
let points = [];
for(var angle = 0; angle < Math.PI * 2; angle += .01) {
  points.push(Math.sin(angle));
}

console.log(points);
```

Now imagine that we want to control the amount of points but still getting a full rotation of 2π:

```
const pointsArr = new Array(10000).fill().map((i) => {
  // how to convert above loop 
});

console.log(pointsArr);
```

Comment: `.map((_, i, a) => Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * i / a.length))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate the array using `Array.from`:

```js
function makePoints(numPoints) {
  const diffBetweenPoints = (Math.PI * 2) / (numPoints - 1);
  return Array.from({ length: numPoints }, (_, i) => Math.sin(i * diffBetweenPoints));
}
console.log(makePoints(5));
```

The second argument provided to `Array.from` is an optional `map` function that behaves identically to `Array.prototype.map`.